# Android - using int value 0 as "null"-equivalent for R.drawable

Tags: android

I'm using an intuitive but perhaps unorthodox shortcut, and I quite simply want to know if it may cause problems, is bad form, or if there is a different, more accepted way of doing it.

The shortcut is: in a function which expects an int which is an R.drawable constant, I sometimes use a 0 to act as an equivalent to passing "null".

Here's a sort of template of how I use this:

`int someDrawable = isSomeCondition() ? R.drawable.somedrawable_identifier : 0;
    mHandler.post(new UpdateSomeUI(someDrawable));`

```
//and, elsewhere in the application,
private class UpdateSomeUI implements Runnable {
    private final int someDrawable;

    public UpdateSomeUI(int someDrawable) {
        this.someDrawable = someDrawable;
    }

    public void run() {
        mSomeImageView.setImageResource(someDrawable);
    }
}
```

It seems to work - that is, so far it's been doing what I want, and so far I have observed no adverse effects like crashes or the creation of quantum singularities within the device.

Is this safe to do?
Is this bad form?
I S'dTFW for some official integer value that would be recognized as "null" in this sort of circumstance, but came up empty. Does anyone know if such a value exists?

Edit:
I realize that the tag "r" isn't referring to the one I want. The tag "android.R" doesn't seem to exist, however. I guess I'll remove the tag for now.

Comment: Having accepted an answer, I seem to be unable to now answer my own question. I am therefore leaving this as a comment.

Looking into the ImageView source code, it seems that setting a Bitmap or other drawable sets the mResource value to zero. Additionally, whenever the mResource value is used significantly, it is guarded with a != 0 check. This pretty strongly supports that 0 is a special value; that no actual resource will ever have '0' as its assigned value. This leads me to cautiously believe that using 0 as null is safe. Still bad form, though, see accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no resource that represents "null" and by passing in an invalid resource id, an exception does get thrown and handled internally (when `getDrawable(0)` is called). The proper thing to do is to only call `UpdateSomeUI(someDrawable)` when there is actually a valid drawable.

Something like

```
//in a method somewhere: 
if(isSomeCondition()) {
    mHandler.post(new UpdateSomeUI(R.drawable.somedrawable_identifier));
}
```

What's wrong with doing it that way?

Comment: The difference is, I want the image to actually disappear when isSomeCondition() stops being true. If I were using Bitmaps, I would be calling setImageBitmap(null) in order to cause the image to disappear from the view; I was trying to do the equivalent with setImageResource(0).

Comment: I suppose the right thing to do would be pass a View.VISIBLE or View.GONE and call setVisibility.

Comment: Then why not hide the ImageView instead?

Answer (score 10):

Found this on android documentation for Resource ID, sub-section constants, hope it helps.

[Resource ID > Constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#constants_2)

Constants
ID_NULL
Added in API level 29
static val ID_NULL: Int
The null resource ID. This denotes an invalid resource ID that is returned by the system when a resource is not found or the value is set to @null in XML.

Value: 0

Comment: Good that you answered even after the question has a marked answer. Good point!

Comment: I hope that wasn't sarcastic haha.. Just thought I'd attach that link as no one else had.

Comment: Is 0 guaranteed to be an invalid resource id before API level 29?